# How to block Microsoft spam email on Hotmail?

Tags: outlook.com, spam-prevention

I am using live.com email. That is also Hotmail. Microsoft always send me a bunch of advertisement mail which is annoying.

How can I block it?

Answer (score 2):

How about you click the unsubscribe button at the bottom?

Hotmail adverts are opt-in.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting spam from just one sender, you can easily block that address with the basic options hotmail offers. However, it might just be simpler to remove yourself from their mailing list (look for the unsubscribe link in the email).

To block a sender, once in the settings for your Hotmail account, look for this:

> Preventing junk email

```
* Filters and reporting
* Safe and blocked senders
```

If you want more control, Hotmail Plus offers more options.

If you really want good spam control, as suggested by Keith in comments, choose a different service. You can also redirect your hotmail to another account to use another service's filter, so you don't have to lose your hotmail address.